# How do I construct a non-binary tree based on the preorder&inorder or postorder&inorder traversal?

Tags: algorithm, tree, inorder, preorder, postorder

Two of the exercises for my Data Structures and Algorithms class sound like this

> Construct the tree whose preorder traversal is: 1, 2, 5, 3, 6, 10, 7,
> 11, 12, 4, 8, 9, and inoder traversal is 5, 2, 1, 10, 6, 3, 11, 7, 12,
> 8, 4, 9.
>
> Construct the tree whose postorder traversal is: 5, 2, 10, 6, 11, 12,
> 7, 3, 8, 9, 4, 1, and inoder traversal is 5, 2, 1, 10, 6, 3, 11, 7,
> 12, 8, 4, 9.

I only have to draw the structure of the tree, without implementing it in a programming language. The thing that makes this tasks harder is that the trees are not binary trees. What techniques could I use to build the trees?

Comment: Yes, that would make sense..but this is one of the possible subjects for my midterm.

Comment: Are you 100% sure they aren't binary trees? If I were you, I would just assume that they are, since this is a requirement for in-order.

Comment: A few useful notes - the first node is pre-order and the last node in post-order is always the root. The second and second to last nodes are one of the children of the root, you can determine which one by looking at their relation to the root in the in-order traversal.

Comment: I am sure, this is how the tree should look like: http://i.imgur.com/RESf0kk.png

Comment: You could define an in-order traversal for generic trees. Why don't we just let Tudor tell us his class' definition for post/pre/inorder traversal and see if that is compatible with general (finite) trees?

Also, the question doesn't specify whether the tree is a binary tree or not? What if you just (try to) build a binary tree anyways?

Comment: Definition of preorder and inorder traversals from the lecture: http://i.imgur.com/6puTTkh.png . This can be applied when the tree is already drawn and I have to do the traversal. When the traversal is given and the tree is requested, a solution could be to assume it's a binary one, as you said.

Comment: @Turdor Ciotlos You can convert the tree in your image to a binary tree that satisfies the conditions. Just move the subtree rooted at `4` to the "right" child of 12. What made you think it couldn't be a binary tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I can give a precise algorithmic solution to this, but I can give a conceptual one that should be sufficient. I think if you could fine-tune it to a well-defined algorithm it would be useful for you and make (that part of) the midterm trivial.

First, think about how an inorder traversal traverses a tree. If you draw the tree so that the leftmost child is to the left (visually) and the other children are to the right (visually) then the inorder traversal loosely goes from left to right. You might run into an issue where it's not quite left to right (because of some overlap between a child of one node and the parent or something like that) but you can always stretch the tree out to make it clearly "left to right". So I take advantage of that by 
starting my tree with the inorder traversal:

```
5 2 1 10 6 3 11 7 12 8 4 9
```

Then the idea is we move nodes up and down according to the preorder traversal. This part is the hard to define part. Basically you move nodes up if they're visited "earlier" and move them down if they're visited later. So, for instance, 1 is to the left of 2 and 5 in the preorder traversal so I raised it "up" in the sense that I made 2 and 5 ancestors (but not necessarily children) of 1. So something like

```
   1
5 2 10 6 3 11 7 12 8 4 9
```

Then you see the 2 which comes before the 5, so I raised 2:

```
    1
  2 
5     10 6 3 11 7 12 8 4 9
```

Then you see a 3 comes before the 6 and 10 in the preorder traversal so we can "raise" it.

```
    1
  2        3
5     10 6   11 7 12 8 4 9
```

And so on. Note that the 3 could eventually be a child of 2 or 1... the tree that satisfies the above constraints isn't unique.

Comment: Thanks! What about postorder&inorder? I know the root is the right-most element of the postorder traversal, but what steps should I take to create the tree?

Comment: I haven't actually tried it, but I am pretty sure you can just invert the logic and pull it down if it comes earlier in the postorder traversal than it does in the inorder traversal (instead of up).